# CSS3 Floating ship animation

Tags: css, animation

I am trying to make a floating effect animation. Basically the element will swing with an axis on its lower part, like in the image bellow:

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-m7IuLfuaIC0/UGJGAikLXII/AAAAAAAAKis/N8NfMwdMExY/s1600/GANGORRA.jpg

I dont know how to settle the 2 movements, and also make it constant.

```
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 
    animation-timing-function: linear;

-webkit-transform: rotateZ(-30deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(-30deg);
        transform: rotateZ(-30deg);

-webkit-transform: rotateZ(30deg);
        -ms-transform: rotateZ(30deg);
        transform: rotateZ(30deg);
```

Comment: can you please provide full code??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```css
#ship
{
  animation: swing 2s infinite ease;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

@keyframes swing
{
  0%{ transform: rotate(-10deg);}
  50%{ transform: rotate(20deg);}
  100%{ transform: rotate(-10deg);}
}
```

```html
<div id="ship">SHIP</div>
```